# Compiler not understanding Nil Coalescing Operator on NSTimeInterval

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I've got code that looks like this:

```swift
let duration = funcThatReturnsAnOptionalNSTimeInterval()

let time = duration ?? otherFuncThatReturnsNSTimeInterval()
```

That is giving me the error:

> Binary operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSTimeInterval?' and 'NSTimeInterval'

Ummmm.....isn't that *exactly* what the `??` operator can be applied to?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably elsewhere.  This runs just fine:

```
func optional() -> NSTimeInterval? {
    return nil
}
func nonOptional() -> NSTimeInterval {
    return 145
}


let duration = optional()
let time = duration ?? nonOptional()
print(time)
```

Perhaps post some more of the surrounding code?

Comment: You're totally right. The otherFuncThatReturnsNSTimeInterval() actually takes one parameter and I was passing it the wrong type. Good job swift compiler!